What statistical test to use with unequal sample sizes for pre and post comparison?
I have two groups of students that undergo different learning methods: A and B. I record their performance on quizzes that are ordinal scale (three questions, each scored from 1 to 5) both before and after undergoing the learning methods. So I have 4 groups: $A_{pre}$, $A_{post}$, $B_{pre}$, and $B_{post}$. Unfortunately, since the quizzes are anonymous, I was unable to pair them. In addition, some students did not fill out the quiz post lecture. Thus, I have $|A_{pre}| > |A_{post}|$ and $|B_{pre}| > |B_{post}|$.
I want to determine if method A and is better than method B. Since none of the groups have the same number of samples, and since I don't have samples that are paired across time, I can't simply compute the per-sample differences, i.e. post lecture score minus pre lecture score, and run stat tests there. I also can't treat all four groups as independent, since $A_{pre}$ and $A_{post}$ are dependent.
What would be the best statistical test to use in this case?

What, if any, is the difference between groups A and B before the learning methods are applied? If I am understanding correctly, I think your interest would be a comparison between Apost and Bpost since those are the groups to which the learning methods were applied, unless there is some other difference between A and B. For the test, I would recommend a randomization, or permutation, test. It is nonparametric and can handle unequal sample sizes.

I assume your data is the sum of the scores on the 3 questions, each score being ordinal (1-5).
I will start the answer by pretending that the scores were not ordinal, but at least interval scale. The first thing to do is to compute the average $A_{pre}$ and $B_{pre}$ values. This is your baseline. You should not compare just $A_{post}$ to $B_{post}$ (as a previous answer had), because you can not say that the baselines where the same (what if group $A$ had lower average scores to begin with?). You really should compute $A_{post}-A_{pre}$ (and same for $B$) for each student,  but you "lost" the pairing info; so we have to use the average as a proxy. Then subtract these averages from each value in $A_{post}$ and $B_{post}$ to obtain 2 new variables we will call $A_{Diff}$ and $B_{Diff}$. Then you can run a 2-sample Welch t-test on these, to compare the means (yes, check normality of $A_{Diff}$ and $B_{Diff}$ first; make sure at a minimum the skewness is mild for both). The Welch t-test will handle the different sample sizes. That is the general idea.
But... You say that your scores are ordinal. Then adding them, to obtain a cumulative score is not a valid mathematical operations; it is also likely that these questions have somehow different degrees of difficulty. So you can not guaranty that $1+3+2=3+1+2=2+2+2=1+1+4=\cdots$. These sums are certainly not interval scale, and are not even guarantied to be ordinal scale. Then, if on top of it, you run any statistical test on these numbers, all bets will be off. W/o going into further discussions on this, you may be interested in this post.
So what should you do?
If this is some kind of homework question, ignore my previous point and use a 2-sample Welch t-test as described earlier. You will not be the first to make this mistake with ordinal variables, and not the last. But you should chastise your instructor for such loose use of mathematics.
If it is for a "real" project, where you want to make actual decisions about teaching methodologies, the options are limited, and far from perfect.
The first thing I would do is plot all the data. A dotplot or equivalent of all scores on all questions, divided by group (A, B) and pre/post. I would also do this for each question separately. That would tell me visually if there really seems to be differences, whether there are identifiable clusters, etc. If nothing jumps at me, I may very well quit there.
If there seems to be a there there, I would just compare $A_{pre}$ to $A_{post}$ for each question separately, using a Mann Whitney U test (MWUt); see wiki for a good overview. MWUt works fine for ordinal data. Do the same for $B_{pre}$ and $B_{post}$. You now have 6 U statistics (one for each question and each group).
The first thing to do is to look at the p-values for all 6 tests; if all tests are significant for, say, $A$ and not $B$, then obviously you have a winner, and you can even attach a statistical significance. Similarly, if none of the tests are significant, then $A$ and $B$ did not have an effect. But if, say again, $A$ is significant for 2 out of 3, and $B$ for only 1 out of 3, I would still pick $A$, but I could not (would not know how to) attach a statistical significance to it. And for some other combinations, I may not know how to pick a "winner" (e.g. $A$ significant for only 1, and $B$ significant for another 1).
You could additionally look at the effects of the interventions. For this, you need to normalize the U statistics (because sample sizes will be different between A and B and between pre and post), by dividing each by $n_1n_2$ (where $n_1$ is the sample size of the first group, $n_2$ the sample size of the 2nd group, in each MWUt). These normalized statistics measure how much stochastically greater the post groups were to the pre groups, for each question (i.e. the efefct of the intervention, on each question, for each group).
You can now evaluate the size of these statistics. Again, maybe the effects of 1 group (whether significant or not) may be larger on all 3 questions compared to the other group; that means that group saw a bigger improvement. Can I attach a significance to this result? No, I have no idea how to do that, but I would still chose that method. You may also reach a decision for other scenarios (e.g. $A$ had a greater effect for 2 out of 3), but again I would not know how to attach any statistical significance to that result (yes, it could be "dumb luck").
Sorry about this, but the use of ordinal data seriously constrains what you can do (in spite of an unfortunately too common practice).
